# Memcached as opposed to DB?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

I have a web app that runs a cron job at midnight everyday and then uses that data to populate an HTML template for the next 24 hours. I do not care about preserving the historical values, just showing the latest ones.

With this in mind, do you see any issues with me just caching the values after the cron job is complete and then just fetching the values from memcached throughout the day for GET requests rather than ever querying a DB (GAE datasotre)?

I am using python and GAE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memcached data is *not* persistent. Your app must not rely on it. It's fine to get it from there for speed, but the cache can be evicted at any time, so you must have a permanent storage as a backup for when the data is not there.

The [memcache documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/overview#When_to_Use_a_Memory_Cache) explains this:

> However, when considering whether to store a value solely in the memcache and not backed by other persistent storage, be sure that your application behaves acceptably when the value is suddenly not available. Values can expire from the memcache at any time, and may be expired prior to the expiration deadline set for the value. For example, if the sudden absence of a user's session data would cause the session to malfunction, that data should probably be stored in the datastore in addition to the memcache.

Comment: OK thanks, didn't realise it could go at any time. Datastore it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well if there is a reason behind you using a cache then I would think it is because making trips to the DB is resource consuming and the response times actually go down as the requests increase. Cache is a temporary store but there are caching softwares out there that let you make use of multiple caching topologies like "replicated cache" in which an object has two copies of an object thus precluding the need to make DB trips and I am gettin the idea from the above quote about memcached that that is not an option available in it. Try using NCache. Or you can read more about it: http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/